# Return statement in try block java . What will be returned by method and why?

Tags: java

I was trying exception handling. below code i was not able to understand.
   Please explain how this works internally

```
public int method()
{
    try
    {
        return 1;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    finally
    {
         return 3;
    }
 }
```

Please explain me how this works in java

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because read a tutorial and indicate very precisely what isn't clear about it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Jeroen: I think his question is, it should return 1, but in theory finally always runs.
Raj: in this case, the method 'll be ended by the return statement.

Comment: I guess this is not a duplicate question as i wanted to know internal working of this . Please go through this code
try
{
 return 1;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 return 2;
}
finally
{
 System.out.println("hello");
}
for above code why value 1 is return

Answer (score 1):

The method will always return 3.Because even if a return statement is there in try block the control will be passed on to finally block.And it will return 3 and the return value from try block will be lost